# How To Call A Void ColdFusion Function With No Arguments

Tags: coldfusion, cffunction

I'm writing a ColdFusion function that is the following:

```
<cffunction name="checkStatusCode" output="false" access="private" returnType="void">
    <cfif result.Responseheader.Status_Code eq "400">
        <cfset isBadRequest = true>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

It is both void and contains no parameters; I understand how I would call it if it had parameters and returned something; I'd simply put the code in a `<cfset>` tag. I simply want to run the function. What tags do I need to put it in?

Comment: Is this inside or outside of a cfc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either this:

```
<cfset checkStatusCode()>
```

or, if you are using cfscript,

```
checkStatusCode();
```

You could probably use `<cfinvoke>` if you tried hard enough.

Comment: Maybe there are pro `<cfinvoke>` and anti-`<cfinvoke>` people?